# GitLab CLI - fetch all repositories by organization

Tags: gitlab, command-line-interface

Is there any way to fecth **all repos** by **organization** using gitlab cli? As far as I see there are the following flags exist:

```
FLAGS
  -a, --all               List all projects on the instance
      --member            Only list projects which you are a member
  -m, --mine              Only list projects you own (default true)
  -o, --order string      Return repositories ordered by id, created_at, or other fields (default "last_activity_at")
  -p, --page int          Page number (default 1)
  -P, --per-page int      Number of items to list per page. (default 30)
  -R, --repo OWNER/REPO   Select another repository using the OWNER/REPO or `GROUP/NAMESPACE/REPO` format or full URL or git URL
  -s, --sort string       Return repositories sorted in asc or desc order
      --starred           Only list starred projects
```

Folling that, `-R` looks like what I need, but /REPO argument also needed to be there, so it makes it almost useless for our case.

glab version: 1.24.1